# ASP.NET MVC a better way to post model ID?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post

I have a ViewModel I am binding to a view:

```
ProductViewModel model = Mapper.Map<Product, ProductViewModel>(product);
return View(model);
```

The view (and viewmodel) is used to edit a `Product` so `ProductViewModel` has an ID property that corresponds to the ID in the database.

And to Post the ID back to the Controller I am doing this in my form on the view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
```

*Even though this works* - I was wondering whether there was a better way to Post the ID back to the Controller? Route Values maybe? or is this a fairly standard pattern/approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I have a GET action that includes the id in my route: `/Products/Edit/1` then I usually keep it as a route value:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, EditProductViewModel model)
```

This is purely a preference of mine, though. There is no right or wrong way to do it.

The nice thing about this method is you no longer need to pass it in using a Hidden value since it is part of the URL. Actually, if you do pass it in with a Hidden value I believe it will be ignored.

Alternatively, since id is part of the route, you don't even need to have a separate parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditProductViewModel model)

public class EditProductViewModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Again, this is purely a preference thing.

Comment: I don't think hidden fields are ignored, they seem to be mapped to the model object just like a visible field is.

Comment: @Greg I meant if you had a hidden field called `id` and you had a route value called `id` the route value would win.

Comment: It's much of a muchness but I think this is the more elegant solution.

Comment: @Dismissile I think this is most elegant option also but could be made even better by removing the `int id` arg from the Edit method, as MVC should map the ID onto the `EditProductViewModel` automagically

Comment: Actually I quite like the idea of the `id` parameter.  It keeps the id separate from the viewmodel if you actually wanted to reuse viewmodels between views (not that I do).  It's nice to see a different option presented.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is, it depends.

Is your *entire* object being edited and posted back?  If so I'd suggested posting back the ID as part of the model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditProductViewModel model)
```

Which I think is a perfectly valid thing to do.  However be careful.  If the resource being edited is a protected resource, ensure you validate the user has the correct privileges.

If it's a partial edit, perhaps just editing a comment through an Ajax call I'd probably be more tempted to do:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, string comment)
```

As creating a Model in that scenario I would see as overkill ... privilege problem still applies though :)

All that being said, I'm no expert myself :)

Incidentally ... I don't think there's anything wrong with the hidden field, I use it all the time.  However it's an ajax call it may not be needed as it would be part of your posting ajax call.